# Entity Framework 4 - How to Insert Records with Joiner Tables C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I've been coding a very sizable project and I have run into trouble with EF4 and joiner table operations.

Suppose we have the following SQL table defintions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQLEntity](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Field1] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [nvarchar] (256),
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SQLEntity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( 
        [Id] ASC 
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Util_LookupValues](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Util_LookupValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Xref_EntityValues](
    [SQLEntityId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [LookupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Xref_PositionBenefits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [SQLEntityId] ASC,
        [LookupId] ASC
    )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Xref_EntityValues] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Xref_EntityValues_Entity] FOREIGN KEY([SQLEntityId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SQLEntity] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Xref_EntityValues] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Xref_EntityValues_Entity]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Xref_EntityValues]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Xref_EntityValues_Util_LookupValues] FOREIGN KEY([LookupId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Util_LookupValues] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Xref_EntityValues] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Xref_EntityValues_Util_LookupValues]
GO
```

Once a domain model is crated based on these tables you'd end up with two Entities:
SqlEntity and Util_LookupValues.

At this point that the Util_LookupValues is a table whose values have been defined for lookups only! the Xref_EntityValues is a joiner table that would tie together the Entity object to the lookup value, allowing us to have a meny to meny relationship between the two, preserving the "lookup" functionality for the lookup table.

Util_LookupValues contents

```
Id   Description
---  ------------
1    Person
2    Car
```

If no changes are added to the domain model (Lets for the purpose of this question call it DataEntities) then tying up a SQLEntity with Util_LookupValues objects whose PK is 1 and 2 would be done as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Util_LookupValues> lookupValues = DataEntities.Util_LookupValues.Where( lv => lv.Id == 1 || lv.Id == 2);

SQLEntity entity = new SQLEntity();
entity.Field1 = "some field";
entity.Field2 = "another field";
entity.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;

foreach(Util_LookupValues val in lookupValues)
{
    entity.Util_LookupValues.Add(val);     
}

DataEntities.SQLEntities.Add(entity);
DataEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Problem though is that instead of just adding values to the Xref_EntityValues, this code also adds a copy of 1 and 2 to the Util_LookupValues with new keys!
The resulting database is as follows:

```
SQL Entity:
Id  Field1       Field2         DateAdded
-- -------      ------         ----------
1   some field  another field  04/04/2012

Xref_EntityValues:
SQLEntityId   LookupId
-----------   ---------
1              3
1              4

and Util_LookupValues:
Id   Description
---  ------------
1    Person
2    Car
3    Person
4    Car
```

How do I make it that Util_LookupValues only has the 2 original records and the Xref_EntityValues has the proper foreign keys?

```
Xref_EntityValues:
SQLEntityId   LookupId
-----------   ---------
1              1
1              2

Util_LookupValues:
Id   Description
---  ------------
1    Person
2    Car
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am somewhat constrained on how much changes can I make to SQL. As this code is used in a Silverlight 4 project, making changes to the Domain Model also requires changes to all WCF RIA services and an extremely large code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this line...

```
IEnumerable<Util_LookupValues> lookupValues = DataEntities.Util_LookupValues
    .Where( lv => lv.Id == 1 || lv.Id == 2);
```

...and this line...

```
DataEntities.SQLEntities.Add(entity);
```

... use *the same* instance of the `DataEntities` context? Your code snippet indicates that but perhaps it's "pseudo code".

If the instances are different you get the duplication of entities, yes.

So, you have three options:

- Make sure the context instances are the same.
- Attach the returned `Util_LookupValues` to the second context:

  ```
  foreach(Util_LookupValues val in lookupValues)
  {
      DataEntities.Util_LookupValues.Attach(val);
      entity.Util_LookupValues.Add(val);     
  }
  ```
- Don't perform the first query at all. Instead create "stub" entities and attach them:

  ```
      var val = new Util_LookupValues { Id = 1 };
      DataEntities.Util_LookupValues.Attach(val);
      entity.Util_LookupValues.Add(val);     

      val = new Util_LookupValues { Id = 2 };
      DataEntities.Util_LookupValues.Attach(val);
      entity.Util_LookupValues.Add(val);
  ```

  This work because EF only needs to know the primary key property value when you attach an object to the context to establish a new relationship.

Comment: OMG, Thank you, thank you, thank you! I never realized that because the look-up entities were retrieved via a different instance of the DomainContext (DataEntities) they were being re-duplicated! I guess the first thing I have to do is re-attach them and then proceed with the rest of the code. I will try that right away!